# Emit only unique values - or if a certain period of time has passed since last emit

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Given that I have an `IObservable<int> values` that receives these values (at the specified time):

```
Time (secs)  Value
1            4
2            3
3            5
4            5
10           5
11           6
```

*Update: The time column is only shown to examplify the timing of when values are received. The Observable only contains simple int values.*

I want to output a value if:

1. it is different from the previous value, or
2. more than 5 seconds have passed since previous value

Expected output: 4, 3, 5, 5, 6

So something like:

```
void Foo(IObservable<int> values)
{
    ...
    values
        .Something()
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine(x))
        ...
}
```

I sense, that I need some combination of `GroupByUntilChanged()` and `Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))`, but my Reactive-fu is rather rusty...

Comment: All you need to do is look at the last value and compare  against current time.

Comment: Maybe I was a bit unclear in the question: I only receive int values. The time-column showed in the example input is just to show when the value is received. I'll update the OP.

Comment: The only way you can determine the LAST TIME data was accessed is to put a timestamp on the data.   Without the time you cannot determine if more than 5 seconds have passed.

Comment: Your example output should be 43556?

Comment: @Shlomo yes, sorry! I have updated the OP. ;)

Comment: @jdweng So would you do a .TimeStamp() and then a .Scan() ?

Comment: Collect Time and Value for each emit.  Then compare last emit time to current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two conditions by themselves are easy, merging it is a bit tricky:

Different from previous value:

```
source.DistintUntilChanged()
```

Output if quiet for 5 seconds:

```
source
    .TimeInterval()
    .Where(timedT => timedT.Interval > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    .Select(timedT => timedT.Value)
```

For merging, I would apply an indexer, merge the two separate solutions, then filter on the indexer to remove duplicates, which looks like this:

```
var result = source
    .Select((val, index) => (val, index))           // Add indexer
    .Publish(_indexedSource => Observable.Merge(
        _indexedSource
            .DistinctUntilChanged(t => t.val),

        _indexedSource
            .TimeInterval()
            .Where(timedT => timedT.Interval > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .Select(timedT => timedT.Value)
    ))
    .DistinctUntilChanged(t => t.index)            // Filter out items with same index
    .Select(t => t.val);                           // Remove indexing
```

If you want to test it, you need to pass the scheduler into the `TimeInterval` function, which looks like this:

```
var ts = new TestScheduler();

// The sequence described in question.
var source = ts.CreateHotObservable(
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(1 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond, 4),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(2 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond, 3),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(3 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond, 5),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(4 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond, 5),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(10 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond, 5),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(11 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond, 6),
    ReactiveTest.OnCompleted<int>(12 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)
);

// solution
var testResult = source
    .Select((val, index) => (val, index))
    .Publish(_indexedSource => Observable.Merge(
        _indexedSource
            .DistinctUntilChanged(t => t.val),
        _indexedSource
            .TimeInterval(ts)
            .Where(timedT => timedT.Interval > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .Select(timedT => timedT.Value)
    ))
    .DistinctUntilChanged(t => t.index)
    .Select(t => t.val);

// Test assertions
var observer = ts.CreateObserver<int>();
testResult.Subscribe(observer);

var expected = ts.CreateHotObservable(
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(1 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond, 4),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(2 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond, 3),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(3 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond, 5),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(10 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond, 5),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(11 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond, 6),
    ReactiveTest.OnCompleted<int>(12 * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)
);
ts.Start();
ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(expected.Messages, observer.Messages);
```

Comment: It works like a charm. My OP example was very simplified compared to the actual use case, but your example gave me precisely what I needed to make it all work (tests included). So thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

On closer reflection, one of my colleagues reminded me of the power of .Scan() and DistinctUntilChanged() in combination. So for posterity I will add that solution here as well:

```
var result = source
    .TimeInterval(scheduler)
    .Scan((prev, curr) =>
    {
        if (prev.Value != curr.Value || curr.Interval > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            return curr;
        else
            return prev;
    })
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

Reactive Extensions truly follows Perl's old motto TIMTOWTDI. ;-)

Comment: Not really sure, why this got a downvote, as it gets the same job done.

Comment: I didn't give the downvote, but I should: This fails the case where the same value is repeated after > 5 seconds because of the `DistinctUntilChanged` operator.